# i have 2 image file uploaded but only one save on folder

Tags: php, loops

i have situation in here and i am running out of idea,when i upload 2 image there is only one image saved in the folder. anyone can help me on my script?

```
$q = "SELECT h.hop_id,h.hop_name, n.ne_site_name, n.ne_site_code, f.fe_site_name, f.fe_site_code, p.photo_id, p.ne_photo_image, p.fe_photo_image
FROM hop AS h 
    LEFT JOIN ne_site AS n ON(h.ne_site_id = n.ne_site_id)
    LEFT JOIN fe_site AS f ON(h.fe_site_id = f.fe_site_id)
    LEFT JOIN photo AS p ON(h.hop_id = p.hop_id)
    WHERE h.hop_id = '".$_GET['kode']."'
    "; 
    $r = mysql_query($q) or die ($q);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array ($r);

$tmp_file = $_FILES[ne_photo_image][tmp_name];
$size = $_FILES[ne_photo_image][size];
$file = $_FILES[ne_photo_image][name];

$tmp_file1 = $_FILES[fe_photo_image][tmp_name];
$size1 = $_FILES[fe_photo_image][size];
$file1 = $_FILES[fe_photo_image][name];


            $q = mysql_query("insert into photo(ne_photo_image,fe_photo_image,title,hop_id)
        values ('$file','$file1','$_POST[photo_name_id]','$_POST[photo_hop_id]')") or die(mysql_error());
            if ($q) {
            } else {
                echo 'gagal';
            }

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'image/' . $file)
```

and this  my form :

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Hop Name :<?echo "$data[hop_name]"?>
                <input type='hidden' name='photo_hop_id' value='<?echo"$data[hop_id]"?>'>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <table border="0"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "100%">
    <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Near End Site Name : <?echo "$data[ne_site_name]"?>
                        </br>
                    Near End Site Id : <?echo "$data[ne_site_code]"?>
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    Far End Site Name : <?echo "$data[fe_site_name]"?>
                        </br>
                    Far End Site Id : <?echo "$data[fe_site_code]"?>
                </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?  $pm1= mysql_query("SELECT photo_name FROM photo_name WHERE photo_name_id = 1");
                        $dpm1 = mysql_fetch_array ($pm1);echo"$dpm1[0]"?> 
                    <input type='hidden' name='photo_name_id' value='<?echo"$dpm1[0]"?>'> :  
                    <input type="file" name="ne_photo_image">
                </td>
                <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width= "50%"> 
                    <?echo "$dpm1[0]"?> : <input type="file" name="fe_photo_image">
                </td>
    </tr>   

</table>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="tambah" />
</form>
```

many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `move_uploaded_file` for the first file only and that's the reason second image is not being uploaded. Use another one for the second image.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'image/' . $file)
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file1, 'image/' . $file1)
```

UDPATE : For debugging purpose

```
if(! move_uploaded_file($tmp_file1, 'image/' . $file1))
{
  echo $_FILES["fe_photo_image"]["error"];
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error message? Can you try echoing `$file1` and see if you're getting a filename?

Comment: i already try that, but not working. the result still same, just one image save on the folder

Comment: there is no error, the filename works fine and already insert on the database,

Comment: Just to be sure, which image is not being uploaded? `fe_photo_image` or `ne_photo_image` ?

Comment: this my database result : 80    Chrysanthemum.jpg  Lighthouse.jpg  1   Site outdoor. and fe_photo_image are not saving on the folder. sory for my english

Comment: both oh filename are insert, but the image still only one copied to the images folder

Comment: i am fool man... thanks for the answer.. i edit the wrong script... than you very much

Comment: @MeijuNainggolan You're welcome. And no worries, it happens to the best of us